# BigQuery: How do DML operations affect storage class (Active vs Long-Term storage)

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say I have a table whose storage is currently billed under long-term storage.  I then update one column on all rows of this table via a DML Update.  Does that move the entire table back to being in the active storage class?

Does performing other DML operations like Delete, Insert, or Merge on a table partition also cause the entire partition to go back into active storage?

Answer (score 3):

> Let's say I have a table whose storage is currently billed under long-term storage. I then update one column on all rows of this table via a DML Update. Does that move the entire table back to being in the active storage class?

Yes, it does, because you have modified the table, and long-term storage only applies to tables that [have not been modified for more than 90 days](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#long-term-storage).

> Does performing other DML operations like Delete, Insert, or Merge on a table partition also cause the entire partition to go back into active storage?

Yes, because DML operations on a partition modify that partition.